# I got an Exception while synchronizing the database in my deployed software

Tags: c#, wpf, synchronization, setup-deployment, microsoft-sync-framework

I have developed one online/offline software in which I have used Microsoft sync framework 2.1. In this application I created customized setup(using installer class) so that I can synchronize the local database before using it. For testing purpose I installed this software on multiple systems, I did installation and synchronization successfully on all test system. But when I want to synchronize the database using my installed software then it synchronize successfully on some systems and give an exception on some systems. I have used same logic for synchronization in the installer class and in my application. Here is my synchronization code.

```
SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection(DataAccess.SqlServerCon);
SqlConnection clientConn = new SqlConnection(DataAccess.SqlCon);
serverConn.Open();
clientConn.Open();
SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();

// Create provider for SQL Server
SqlSyncProvider serverProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("Scope1", serverConn);

// Set the command timeout and maximum transaction size for the SQL 
SqlSyncProvider clientProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("Scope1", clientConn);

// Set Local provider of SyncOrchestrator to the server provider
syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = serverProvider;
serverProvider.ObjectSchema = ".dbo";
// Set Remote provider of SyncOrchestrator to the client provider
syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = clientProvider;

// Set the direction of SyncOrchestrator session to Upload and Download
syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;
try
{
   // Create SyncOperations Statistics Object
   SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();

   // Display the Statistics
   MessageBox.Show("Start Time: " + syncStats.SyncStartTime);
   MessageBox.Show("Total Changes Uploaded: " + syncStats.UploadChangesTotal);
   MessageBox.Show("Total Changes Downloaded: " + syncStats.DownloadChangesTotal);
   MessageBox.Show("Complete Time: " + syncStats.SyncEndTime);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
  serverConn.Close();
  serverConn.Dispose();
  clientConn.Close();
  clientConn.Dispose();
```

I am getting this error at line `SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();`

I am getting this error shown in below fig.[image]

Comment: Did you ensure that the command syntax is correct and have you checked the inner exception for any store-specific errors?

Comment: syncOrchestrator.Synchronize(); is library function in which exception occurred so I cannot check command syntax here. but while installation this code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I got it's answer. In windows 7 we need to change security setting of our installation folder. We need to give full control to the user so that database will not be read-only. That exception occurred because my local database was read-only for user and while installation synchronization is done by system and for system database is not read-only.